# Join multiple lines into one

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question about how can I join multiple lines into one.

I have a table like this

```
Code Line Text
------------------------
001  1    some text
002  1    some text
002  2    next some text
003  3    some text
```

The deal is that one code could have multiple lines.

So far I have one dictionary that check if the code exists if not then add that text and its code into the dictionary. But how can I check if there is more than one code (multiple lines) and merge into one?

```
foreach (var item in file)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(item.CODE))
    {
        dict.Add(item.CODE, item.NOTE);
    }
}
```

Could be with another option not only dictionaries, thanks to all for the help!

**EDIT** Thanks to [@Rufus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2052655/rufus-l) answer I solved my problem. Solution:

```
  foreach (var item in file)
                {
                    if (!dict.ContainsKey(item.CODE.ToString()))
                    {
                        dict.Add(item.CODE.ToString(), item.NOTE.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dict[item.CODE.ToString()] += " " + item.NOTE.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Do you want the dictionary values to remain a string, and simply concatenate the string with the new string(s), or would a `List<string>` be better, where each line is an item in the list?

Comment: `else { dict[item.CODE] += Environment.NewLine + item.NOTE; }` will concatenate each line to the previous one, separated by a newline character

Comment: Hi Rufus, what I want is that if I have a code more than once (because the text is in two lines) I want to only have one code and one single line for the text. I don't know that makes sense?

Comment: Then just remove the `Environment.NewLine +` from my earlier comment

Comment: For the line `6 3 some text`, what should we do since we don't have lines 1 and 2? That kind of details can have an important impact on the solution.

Comment: Please convert your solution into an answer that you can mark as accepted in due time for this question to come to a closure.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to *group* the `Text` on `Code`; if `group` has *several* items they should be *ordered* by `Line`. You can try using *Linq*

Providing that `file` implements `IEnumerable<MyClass>` where `MyClass` has `Code`, `Line`, `Text` properties (fields) you can put

```
var dict = file
  .GroupBy(item => item.Code)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                group => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, group
                  .OrderBy(item => item.Line)
                  .Select(item => item.Text)));
```